# How to implement authorization_code grant flow in golang to login to Azure AD

Tags: azure, go, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I would like to implement authorization grant flow for an application in golang.
The app will then read (delegated) azure resources the user has access to.

Already combed through several dozens of samples in github and everywhere else, but they are either incomplete or doesn't bring up the login prompt as expected.

I am looking for a sample that uses purely REST (preferable).
If not, using adal/msal, "golang.org/x/oauth2/microsoft" or any other method.
Also need to get an access token from the request as the Go sdk for Azure doesnt cover  all resources and I'd like to use the access token to make REST calls.

[image]

Any pointers to working code sample would be highly appreciated.
Note: I can successfully login with other methods like client credentials. Issue is only getting auth code flow to work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for reaching out. As you have noted, the [Azure SDK for Go](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/go/azure-sdk-authorization) does not yet support the authorization code flow. You should be able to use the [authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) by following these steps:

1. Request an authorization code by directing the user to the `/authorize` endpoint making sure to add the `offline_access` scope. If successful, the authorize endpoint returns the authorization code.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&response_mode=query
&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read
&state={state}
&code_challenge={code_challenge}
&code_challenge_method=S256
```

2. Redeem the authorization code for an access token using either a client_secret or a certificate credential. If successful, the token response will include an `access_token` and a `refresh_token` which is used to fetch access tokens after the current one expires.

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read
&code=OAAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLWQJVzCTE9UkP3pSx1aXxUjq3n8b2JRLk4OxVXr...
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&grant_type=authorization_code
&code_verifier=ThisIsntRandomButItNeedsToBe43CharactersLong 
&client_secret={client_secret}    // NOTE: Only required for web apps. This secret needs to be URL-Encoded.
```

3. Use the access token to make requests such as getting the signed-in user's messages:

```
GET /v1.0/me/messages
Host: https://graph.microsoft.com
Authorization: Bearer {access_token}
```

4. [Refresh the access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refresh-the-access-token) by submitting another POST request to the `/token` endpoint, this time providing the `refresh_token`:

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=535fb089-9ff3-47b6-9bfb-4f1264799865
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read
&refresh_token={refresh_token}
&grant_type=refresh_token
&client_secret={sampleCredentials}   // NOTE: Only required for web apps. This secret needs to be URL-Encoded
```

Please see additional documentation here to learn more about error handling and refreshing the token: [authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refresh-the-access-token)

Let me know whether this helps and if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks @Diana. My confusion is mainly in the step 1 itself. Do I need to launch a browser instance with this URL and params to trigger an interactive user login? Then I need to capture the output of the session to get the auth code. Is that how it is supposed to function? It'd be great if you clarify these points. – Sumesh 7 hours ago   Delete